# Spring WebFlux OAuth2 JWT configuration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webflux

I'm using this environment:

- spring boot 2.2.6-RELEASE
- spring webflux
- spring-security-oauth2 with JWT token

My application will be a resource server. The authorization server is WSO2 IS.

I realized this SpringSecurityConfig:

```
@Bean
SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeExchange(exchanges ->
        exchanges
        .pathMatchers("/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_openid")

        )
        .csrf().disable()
        .cors()
        .configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())
        .and()
        .oauth2ResourceServer(  oauth2ResourceServer ->
        oauth2ResourceServer.jwt(jwt -> jwt.jwtDecoder(jwtDecoder()))
        );
        return http.build();
    }
private ReactiveJwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {

        JwkSetUriReactiveJwtDecoderBuilder builder =NimbusReactiveJwtDecoder.withJwkSetUri(env.getProperty("spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwks-uri"));
        try {
            builder.webClient(sigecroWebClient());
        }catch (Exception e) {
            new IllegalStateException("Impossibile proseguire. Avvenuto errore nella creazione del webclient", e);
        }
        return builder.build();
    }
```

Now by reading Spring Security Configuration here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#webflux-oauth2-resource-server I see that, once I provide the issuer-uri, the framework will search the right oauth2 configuration by trying to connect to the Provider Configuration endpoint.

So far so good. I provided both issuer-uri and jwks-uri but I got several problems.

By debugging I arrived to this class `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils` and more exactly to this method

```
private static Map<String, Object> getConfiguration(String issuer, URI... uris) {
    String errorMessage = "Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of " +
            "\"" + issuer + "\"";
    for (URI uri : uris) {
        try {
            RequestEntity<Void> request = RequestEntity.get(uri).build();
            ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> response = rest.exchange(request, typeReference);
            Map<String, Object> configuration = response.getBody();

            if (configuration.get("jwks_uri") == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("The public JWK set URI must not be null");
            }

            return configuration;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            if (!(e instanceof HttpClientErrorException &&
                    ((HttpClientErrorException) e).getStatusCode().is4xxClientError())) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorMessage, e);
            }
            // else try another endpoint
        }
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorMessage);
}
```

As you can see the RestTemplate is used in order to get the Right configuraiont. But in WSO2 the Provider Configuration endpoint needs a basi authentication in order to get the config. I was not able in finding a way to configure spring oportunely. Since I'm in a hurry what I did is to change the `org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils` in this way:

```
class JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils {
    private static final String OIDC_METADATA_PATH = "/.well-known/openid-configuration";
    private static final String OAUTH_METADATA_PATH = "/.well-known/oauth-authorization-server";
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils.class.getName());
    private static final RestTemplate rest = new RestTemplate();
    private static Properties props;
    private static final ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>> typeReference =
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {};
            static {
                Resource res = new ClassPathResource("configuration.properties");
                if( res.exists() ) {
                    props = new Properties();
                    try {
                        props.load(res.getInputStream());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        LOGGER.error("Errore nel caricamento delle properties");
                    }
                }
            }
            static Map<String, Object> getConfigurationForOidcIssuerLocation(String oidcIssuerLocation) {
                return getConfiguration(oidcIssuerLocation, oidc(URI.create(oidcIssuerLocation)));
            }

            static Map<String, Object> getConfigurationForIssuerLocation(String issuer) {
                URI uri = URI.create(issuer);
                return getConfiguration(issuer, oidc(uri), oidcRfc8414(uri), oauth(uri));
            }

            static void validateIssuer(Map<String, Object> configuration, String issuer) {
                String metadataIssuer = "(unavailable)";
                if (configuration.containsKey("issuer")) {
                    metadataIssuer = configuration.get("issuer").toString();
                }
                if (!issuer.equals(metadataIssuer)) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("The Issuer \"" + metadataIssuer + "\" provided in the configuration did not "
                            + "match the requested issuer \"" + issuer + "\"");
                }
            }

            private static Map<String, Object> getConfiguration(String issuer, URI... uris) {
                String errorMessage = "Unable to resolve the Configuration with the provided Issuer of " +
                        "\"" + issuer + "\"";
                for (URI uri : uris) {
                    try {
                        RequestEntity<Void> request = null;
                        if( props != null && 
                            !props.isEmpty() && 
                            StringUtils.hasText(props.getProperty("oauth2.resourceserver.wel.known.auth.username")) &&
                            StringUtils.hasText(props.getProperty("oauth2.resourceserver.wel.known.auth.password"))) {
                            String username = props.getProperty("oauth2.resourceserver.wel.known.auth.username");
                            String password = props.getProperty("oauth2.resourceserver.wel.known.auth.password");
                            String basic = Base64.encodeBase64String((username+":"+password).getBytes());
                            request = RequestEntity.get(uri).header("Authorization", "Basic "+basic).build();
                        }else {
                            request = RequestEntity.get(uri).build();
                        }


                        ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> response = rest.exchange(request, typeReference);
                        Map<String, Object> configuration = response.getBody();

                        if (configuration.get("jwks_uri") == null) {
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The public JWK set URI must not be null");
                        }

                        return configuration;
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        throw e;
                    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        if (!(e instanceof HttpClientErrorException &&
                                ((HttpClientErrorException) e).getStatusCode().is4xxClientError())) {
                            throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorMessage, e);
                        }
                        // else try another endpoint
                    }
                }
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorMessage);
            }

            private static URI oidc(URI issuer) {
                return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(issuer)
                        .replacePath(issuer.getPath() + OIDC_METADATA_PATH)
                        .build(Collections.emptyMap());
            }

            private static URI oidcRfc8414(URI issuer) {
                return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(issuer)
                        .replacePath(OIDC_METADATA_PATH + issuer.getPath())
                        .build(Collections.emptyMap());
            }

            private static URI oauth(URI issuer) {
                return UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(issuer)
                        .replacePath(OAUTH_METADATA_PATH + issuer.getPath())
                        .build(Collections.emptyMap());
            }
}
```

I'm wondering if this is the correct way to proceed o there is a better solution than extend/modify a source class of spring.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Thank you
Angelo

Comment: no it is not the correct way since you have rewritten the source code. OpenID, jwt,jwk, oauth2 etc. is a standard, and the provider you have chosen does not follow the standard. So you should contact the the 3rd part vendor and get them to fix it. As soon as someone updates your SpringSecurity library, your application will break.

Comment: @ThomasAndolf I guess the point here it's not the compliance or not to the standard. The point is that by default in WSO2 IS endpoints are protected for security reason. And honestly I can't blame them. Once I provide the basic authentication, all the Spring security stuffs work pretty good. The point here is: how to configure the `JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils` in order to manage basic authentication (or others) for rest template when needed?

Comment: jwks are not a secret. What they are providing you through that endpoint is a public key to verify the integrity of the jwt, that they havn't been tampered with.

You are missing the point. All the code in the spring security class is written static. because it is a standard and has no need to be customised. If you need to customise it you'll have to file an issue with spring and ask them to make it more modular.

There is no right or wrong here. Im just saying what will happen, when you update, you will break your entire application.